# How do I find the name of an image by clicking on it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, find

I just want to be able to find out what the image name is so that I can assign it to a variable and use it for some of my other jQuery functions. How do I do this? I don't mind if the method finds the source of the image as I can trim it down to the part I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To grab the image with path:**

```
$('img').click(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**This should grab you the name of just the image, regardless of path:**

```
$('img').click(function()
{
    var test = $(this).attr('src').split('\/');
    alert(test[test.length-1]);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/SqBjq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');

    // Manipulate the src as you like...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var imagename=this.src;
    alert(imagename);
});
```

Comment: *Probably* quicker than `$(this).attr('src')`